# Dynamically link libgnat

Tags: static, linker, shared, ada, gnat

I'm trying to compile a very simple **ADA** code. Everything works like a charm but on one computer my executable is link dynamically to **libgnat** whereas on the other computer it's linked statically. In both cases I use **gnatmake** tool.

Any idea why it's happening?
Do you know a way to force GNAT to dynamically link libraries?

Comment: Which Gnat versions, which OS? Is the statically linked one mingw (for Windows?)

Comment: @BrianDrummond Linux only. libgnat-4.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the binder's `-shared` switch. If you are using project files, you can use:

```
project Foo is
    ...
    package Binder is
       for Switches ("Ada") use ("-shared");
    end Binder;
```

end Foo;

Comment: This fails with: ```gnatbind: invalid switch: --shared```